# Creating Array or ArrayList from class ojects

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have been working on this for a while, but can't quite seem to figure out how to add an item to an ArrayList. I would like to add grocItem (should be 7 grocItems from user input from for loop)  into an ArrayList of grocList:

```
        public class ItemData{
        public ItemData(String name, double cost, int priority){

        Main.(ArrayList grocList).add(grocItem);

          // Main.groclist.add(grocItem);



    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

    public static List<ItemData> itemData = new ArrayList<ItemData>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        //String name1;
        //int priority1; 
        //double cost1;

       String[] item  = new String[7];

        for (i=0; i<item.length; i++)  {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter item name " + i);
            String name = keyboard.next();
            Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the price of item " + i);
            double cost = keyboard2.nextDouble();
            Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Priority Number " + i);
            int priority = keyboard3.nextInt();

            ItemData grocItem = new ItemData(name, cost, priority);
        }
        //How do I add grocItem to an Array list of other grocItems (6 grocItems from user input array item)
        Main.itemData.add(groclist);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code, add the method inside the loop.

```
for (i=0; i<item.length; i++)  {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter item name " + i);
            String name = keyboard.next();
            Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the price of item " + i);
            double cost = keyboard2.nextDouble();
            Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Priority Number " + i);
            int priority = keyboard3.nextInt();

            ItemData grocItem = new ItemData(name, cost, priority);
            itemData.add(grocItem ); // add here 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `ItemData` object to your arraylist inside your loop:

```
for (i=0; i<item.length; i++)  {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter item name " + i);
        String name = keyboard.next();
        Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the price of item " + i);
        double cost = keyboard2.nextDouble();
        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Priority Number " + i);
        int priority = keyboard3.nextInt();

        ItemData grocItem = new ItemData(name, cost, priority);
        itemData.add(groclist); // <-- add to arraylist inside the loop

}
```